# Degree of field extension $F_{p}(X^p,Y^p) \subset F_{p}(X,Y) $

Tags: extension-field, irreducible-polynomials

What is the degree of the following field extension?

$$ K=F_{p}(X^p,Y^p) \subset  F_{p}(X,Y)=L  $$

Because of $ F_{p}(X^p,Y^p) \subset_{(1)} F_{p}(X,Y^p) \subset_{(2)}  F_{p}(X,Y)  $

and $(1)$ the minimal polynomial $T^p-X^p$ and $(2)$ the polynomial $T^p - Y^p$ it follows $ [L:K] \leq p^2$

So why is $T^p-X^p$ irreducible and how can I proof that $[L:K] = p^2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: You could take a look at the basis of the extension. Try to find it!

If you can't find the solution, I can elaborate and provide details.

You can also argue that due to the irreducibility of $T^p - X^p$ over $K$ and the irreducibility of $T^p - Y^p$ over $K$: $$ [L:\mathbb{F}_p(X, Y^p)] \leq [K(X):K] = [K(Y):K] = p$$.

**Edit**: I used the Eisenstein criterium but you can argue even easier: $ f= T^p - X^p = (T-X)^p $ and if $ f = g \cdot h $, $ g = (T-X)^k $ and analogous for $h$. But as $X^k \notin K$ for $k \in \mathbb{N} $: $ g, h $ must be units or equal to $f$.

Of course it is not wrong to state that $ T^p - X^p $ is irreducible over $ \mathbb{F}_p[X^p,Y^p] $ according to the Eisenstein criterion since $X^p$ is prime. The irreducibility over $ K $ follows with the Gauss Lemma for polynoms.

**Now to the basis:**

I wrote this proof according to my memory and with help of the book "Übungen zur Algebra" by Clemens Fuchs and Gisbert Wüstholz.

The first step is to show that $ \gamma^p \in K = \mathbb{F}_p(X^p, Y^p) $ for arbitrary $ \gamma \in L = \mathbb{F}_p(X,Y) $.

Let $ \gamma = \frac{\sum a_{ij} X^i Y^j}{\sum b_{kl} X^kY^l} $ with coefficients $ a_{ij}, b_{kl} \in \mathbb{F}_p $. Since $L$ has characteristic $p$, you can state that:

$$ \gamma^p = \frac{(\sum a_{ij} X^i Y^j)^p}{(\sum b_{kl} X^kY^l)^p} = \frac{\sum a_{ij}^p (X^p)^i (Y^p)^j}{\sum b_{kl}^p (X^p)^k (Y^p)^l} \in K $$

The next step is to proof that $ L = K[X,Y] $. Obviously is $ K[X,Y] $ a subring of $ L $, so we only have to show $ L \subseteq K[X,Y] $. Every $ a \in L $ has the structure: $ a = \frac f g $ for $ f,g \in \mathbb{F}_p[X,Y]$. We can write:

$$ a = \frac f g = fg^{p-1}(\frac 1 g)^p $$

Therefore: $ a \in K[X,Y] $ because $ f,g \in \mathbb{F}_p[X,Y] \subseteq K[X,Y] $ and $ (\frac 1 g)^p \in L $.

We now show: $ P = \{ X^i Y^j \}_{0 \leq i,j \leq p-1}$ is a $K$-basis for $L$.

We have shown that every element in $ \mathbb{F}_p(X,Y) $ can be written as a linear combination of monomials $ X^i Y^j $. Since $X^p,Y^p \in K $, all these monomials are $K$-multiples of elements in $P$. We know now: $P$ is a generating system for $ L $.

Let

$$ \sum\limits_{0 \leq i,j \leq p-1} f_{ij}X^iY^j = 0 $$

for $ f_{ij} \in K $. After multiplying with a common divisor we are allowed to assume that all $ f_{ij} \in \mathbb{F}_p[X^p,Y^p] $ and we can write them as:

$$ f_{ij} = \sum\limits_{k,l \geq 0} a_{ijkl} X^{pk}Y^{pl} $$

with coefficients $ a_{ijkl} \in \mathbb{F}_p $.

All together:
$$ \sum\limits_{ 0 \leq i,j \leq p-1 \; ; \; k,l \geq 0 } a_{ijkl} X^{pk+i}Y^{pl+j} = 0 $$

After all this we can now compare the coefficients and: $ a_{ijkl} = 0 $ for all $ i,j,k,l $ which means $ f_{ij} = 0 $ for all $ 0 \leq i,j \leq p - 1 $.

That's everything we need to know to say that $ P $ is linearly independent.

And therefore: $$ [L : K] = p^2 $$.

**Note:** There is a much more elegant way to do this since we now know much more that just the degree of the field extension. Maybe I find the time to write it here.

Comment: Could you argue: Obviously $[\mathbb{F}_p(X^p, Y):\mathbb{F}_p(X^p, Y^p)]=p$ (minimal polynomial $T^p-Y^p$). Assume $X^0,...,X^{p-1}$ is linear dependent over $[\mathbb{F}_p(X^p, Y)]$ then there exists a nonzero polynomial $P$ so that $P(X) = 0$. Thats a contradiction to X being transcendental over $\mathbb{F}_p$? I am not quite sure with this? How did you find and proof your basis?

Comment: First: I wouldn't say that P(X) = 0 since your basis vectors are linear dependent only over $K$ in which no such $X$ exists. Moreover try to find a basis for $L$ over $K$ since you know the degrees of the other extensions already. (I will post my solution in which I use a basis later here.)